# Constexpr with new operator

Tags: c++, c++14

I use C++14, can I use `constexpr` like that:

```
constexpr Myclass* obj = new Myclass()
```

I get some compilation errors, also tried to google but all examples without dynamic allocation.

Comment: As evident from the errors, no, it's not allowed. In C++20 `new` can be used in `constexpr` in some limited ways, but not in the way you did it (you must deallocate at compile-time too, the allocation can't leak to runtime).

Comment: why use `new` at all? why not `constexpr Myclass obj;` ?

Comment: I need to pass the pointer to object to another funtion.

Comment: @user3770585  If an object is defined as `constexpr MyClass obj`,  `&obj` produces a pointer to `obj` that can be passed to another function.   (Assuming `const` qualifiers, etc, are correct).

Comment: The function take pointer not const pointer

Comment: Then make a nonconst variable. This doesn't prevent the enclosing function from being constexpr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use C++14, can I use constexpr like that:

No you can't. Evaluation of a `new` expression in a constant expression is never allowed in C++14.

In C++20 it is to some degree, but *only* if you dealloate the allocated memory properly *before the constant expression ends*. In your example the intended constant expression is the initialization of `obj` which does not include any deallocation of the allocated memory.